# strikeout Cyrillic text with latex

Tags: cyrillic, soul, anki

I am trying to use the `soul` package to strike out Cyrillic letters. Instead of the letters being stroked out weird characters are shown.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[russian,english,german]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
тезт \st{ва}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output of latex + dvipng]

As I am using the tex code within [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) and the program uses the toolchain latex + dvipng I would be keen on a solution that works with exactly that toolchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me after I load `inputenc` and `soulutf8`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage[russian,english,german]{babel}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
тезт \st{ва}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes now it works - great. I still got the problem that (if only the \st{} is used) only a dot is displayed in anki. This can be solved adding a space in front of it (for other users of anki).